# Javascript and svg, adding items with a function to a page

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I've created a Javascript function to add my SVG to the page, but I want to change the color of the shape, without having to redraw the shape.

The usual `document.getElementById` method does not work as the shape is being created within a Javascript function.

Any ideas how I could get around this? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

As element is created within javascript, it should be accessible to you. Use fill attribute of the element to change the color of the SVG shape.

```
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', colorValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create and append an svg element via Javascript, you can give it an `id` at the time it is created. Then you can access it via the id.

e.g.

```
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
var myCircle=document.createElementNS(NS,"circle")
myCircle.id="circle1"
...
```

Then, when you want to change the fill color at some later time, your would:

```
circle1.setAttribute("fill","red')
```